# Does chmod modify permissions of FILE... arguments in the order specified?

Tags: unix, posix

Given an invocation of `chmod` with multiple FILE arguments,

```
$ chmod 0xxx FILE-1 FILE-2 FILE-3 ...
```

is there a predictable order of prcessing them? This may matter when `FILE-k` and `FILE-j` are related, e.g. when one is a subdirectory of the other. Say,  `FILE-1` being some directory `d1` and `FILE-2` subdirectory `d1/d2`, i.e., the second argument names a subdirectory of the first argument:

```
$ chmod 0000 d1 d1/d2
chmod: cannot access `d1/d2': Permission denied
```

O.K., this is what I had expected, i.e., reading from left to right reflects the order of processing `FILE...` arguments, `d1`'s permissions are cleared first and, therefore, `chmod` connot then gain access to `d1/d2`. So, the following invocation also works as expected:

```
$ chmod 0000 d1/d2 d1
```

This clears permissions of either directory. But is this order dependence guaranteed, and more generally, does POSIX say something about the matter? Does option `-R` affect the reasoning in some way or other, as regards predictability across Unix systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not specified, all implementations behave *naturally* like you experienced, but there is no guarantee, beware POSIX (**IEEE Std 1003.1-2008, 2016 Edition**) says in `chmod` command manual - *Application Usage*:

> Some implementations of the chmod utility change the mode of a
>   directory before the files in the directory when performing a
>   recursive (-R option) change; others change the directory mode after
>   the files in the directory. If an application tries to remove read or
>   search permission for a file hierarchy, the removal attempt fails if
>   the directory is changed first; on the other hand, trying to re-enable
>   permissions to a restricted hierarchy fails if directories are changed
>   last. Users should not try to make a hierarchy inaccessible to
>   themselves.

Thus any order on the arguments can be applied, you need to use separate commands to ensure the order.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be specified anywhere.

However, the Application Usage section of the  [Manual Page for CHMOD](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) does specify recursive behaviour of the command.

After several experimentation, I obtained the same result as yours on my x86_64 GNU/Linux running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

It seems to work out the permissions from **left to right** and stops when it cannot change permission.

- If you are trying to revoke permissions, then it is better to have the parent directory last. (i.e. leaf to root in the file hierarchy)
- If you are trying to grant permissions, then it is better to have the parent directory first. (i.e. root to leaf in the file hierarchy)